# How to understand source code of C libraries or others?

Tags: c

I can describe myself as beginner in software because I learned just C language in college. I want to understand about some source code that what I see. Today, I was searching about printf() function source code in C-language, so I looked at stdio.h library. (I'm using Windows OS and I have Dev-C compiler).

There are complicated codes that I saw. I'm going to share some of them.

Do I have to understand these codes or just use and leave?

```
#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
__mingw_ovr
__attribute__ ((__format__ (gnu_printf, 2, 3))) __attribute__((nonnull (1,2)))
int asprintf(char **__ret, const char *__format, ...)
{
  register int __retval;
  __builtin_va_list __local_argv; __builtin_va_start( __local_argv, __format );
  __retval = __mingw_vasprintf( __ret, __format, __local_argv );
  __builtin_va_end( __local_argv );
  return __retval;
}
```

I just copied in stdio.h libraries.

Comment: You might do better looking at some open source projects at github.  A language's library code is written to be powerful and efficient in speed and memory use not to be easy to understand.  Most people do not need to understand the C library source code itself, they just need to understand how the library works and how it performs.

Comment: That is not the source code of `printf`. Just its declaration. It's `.h`. `.h` doesn't contain source code (well, it is part of the code, sure. But it is not what code the algorithm, what is done. There is nothing there telling what to do with the "%formats" string and the following arguments, for example). If you want to read source code, you want to read `.c` files, not `.h` (or at least, not just `.h`)

Comment: @chrslg Curiously enough, this part of the header contains code though, a function definition which is not even inline or static.

Comment: This is not standard C; this code is heavily catering to a specific implementation ("`__builtin...`"), apparently gcc on mingw. (I only conclude that from those words appearing int he code.)

Comment: C standard library code is particularly hard to read because they have to be "uglified" in order to avoid using names that are available to the application. Much library code is understandable after de-uglification, but note that the library may take advantage of compiler-specific internal features, such as the `__builtin_va_list` being used here because the standard library's job is to deal with implementation details. You'll have better luck reading something that isn't under such unusual constraints.

Comment: Real world code in the standard library looks like this because for longer than you have been around, generations of programmers have spent considerable effort to squeeze out the last CPU cycle.-- For something accessible, I'd strongly recommend to read Kernighan & Pike's [*The Unix Programming Environment*](https://archive.org/details/UnixProgrammingEnviornment/page/n1/mode/2up); even though it's pre-ANSI C, the differences are trivial and the code is probably what you are looking for: Elegant, concise, explained, from the people who know how to program.

Comment: A more advanced recommendation are probably all of W. Richard Stevens' books; the general one (not specifically concerning networking) is [*Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programming_in_the_Unix_Environment).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments.

i guess those are hard to read for me ,Reading other people's code can be a good exercise and İ will search about Unix. thanks for everthing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to understand these codes or just use and leave?

You **do** need to understand *how* to **use** the library functions properly. Understanding exactly how they are implemented is not necessary.

> If I have to, how can I learn it?

Read the C standard and develop an idea about how to implement the functions you are curious about. Actually being able to implement some of them may take some time and some may even be impossible to implement without compiler specific extensions.